# I'm having an: Error at line 4, character 55: Parse error. primary expression expected via Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm having a problem with a Parse error or something. I'm slowly starting learning JS and implementing in Google Tag Manager with custom HTML. However, my code have an error that I can't find the answer for.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
  
function word_range() {
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
    if ($word_count < 200) { $word_range = '0-200';}
    elseif($word_count < 400) { $word_range = '200-400'; }
    elseif($word_count < 600) { $word_range = '400-600'; }
    elseif($word_count < 800) { $word_range = '600-800'; }
    elseif($word_count < 1000) { $word_range = '800-1000'; }
    elseif($word_count < 1200) { $word_range = '1000-1200'; }
    elseif($word_count < 1400) { $word_range = '1200-1400'; }
    elseif($word_count < 1600) { $word_range = '1400-1600'; }
    elseif($word_count < 1800) { $word_range = '1600-1800'; }
    elseif($word_count < 2000) { $word_range = '1800-2000'; }
    elseif($word_count < 2200) { $word_range = '2000-2200'; }
    elseif($word_count < 2400) { $word_range = '2200-2400'; }
    elseif($word_count < 2600) { $word_range = '2400-2600'; }
    elseif($word_count < 2800) { $word_range = '2600-2800'; }
    elseif($word_count < 3000) { $word_range = '2800-3000'; }
    elseif($word_count < 3200) { $word_range = '3000-3200'; }
    elseif($word_count < 3400) { $word_range = '3200-3400'; }
    elseif($word_count < 3600) { $word_range = '3400-3600'; }
    elseif($word_count < 3800) { $word_range = '3600-3800'; }
    elseif($word_count < 4000) { $word_range = '3800-4000'; }
    elseif($word_count >= 4000) { $word_range = '4000+'; }
    return $word_range;
}

function word_count() {
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
    return $word_count;
}


function post_year() {
    $year_published = the_date( 'Y', $before, $after, $echo );
    return $year_published;
}

function tag_manager_variables() {
    $url = 'http://'. $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    echo "
    <script>
      dataLayer.push = [{
        'wordCount': '". word_count() ."',
        'wordRange': '". word_range() ."',
        'postYear': '". post_year() ."'
      }];
    ";      
}
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'tag_manager_variables' );
</script>
```

Now, the problem seems to be in this line

```
$content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
```

The $post->ID thingy.

The goal with this code is to get the Word count and Range for content grouping in Google Analytics.

Is there a way to fix it?

[View of the Google Tag Manager snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RSeG.png)

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you are trying to run PHP code as Javascript.  At the very least you need to remove the outer <script> tags. The actual HTML output is in the tag_manager_variables function, the rest needs to be parsed on the server, not in the browser.

Comment: Do I need to add the rest of the function code in the function.php of my Wordpress site? Would it work?

Comment: It's been a while that I have worked with Wordpress, but including the whole thing into the function.php should work IMO - the wp_head hook should see to it that the output of tag_manager_variables is appended to the head (but at this point it is a wordpress question, not a GTM question, and I do not clam expertise here).

Comment: It's working. I'll be testing and verifying the data beforehand. Thank you very much.